# AngularJS - Trigger ng-change based on ng-model value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-change

So I've ran into a problem which I have spent some time researching and to no avail, have not found a working solution.

My situation:

- I have rows of checkboxes that fire a function with ng-change (user clicks the checkbox).
- Each checkbox is bound to an ng-model boolean if the box is checked or not.
- For each row, I have a 'select all' checkbox which fires a function that loops through the checkboxes in that row and updates their ng-model's bool to either true or false depending on the select all value.
- On the DOM, the select all works fine and every checkbox bool value is changed, leading to the boxes being checked or unchecked.
- Even if the ng-model bool is changed on the checkboxes from true to false, the ng-change function is not fired.

I have tried implementing watchers on the ng-models to try to fire each ng-change but it doesn't work.

I have tried changing ng-change to ng-click and forcing in the select all function to .trigger('click'), which sort of works but is both hacky and doesn't work correctly if one of the checkboxes are already clicked. This causes it to be the opposite if truthy value.

Is there a way to fire the ng-change function on the checkbox from the controller if the user doesn't directly click the checkbox? I am passing parameters through the function so it has to be fired from the ng-change, not just in the controller.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/qegugetucu/edit?html,css,js,output) is a link to a JS Bin of what I'm trying to accomplish.

If you click the top box (select all) all the lower boxes fill in. If you click one of the lower boxes, it fires the ng-change function which shows some text on the DOM of fired. It doesnt show the text (not firing the ng-change) if the select all button is clicked.

Comment: Show us some code.

Comment: Explanations are cool and all, but really can't show us if you made a small mistake or not. Please show some code as well as an explanation.

Comment: Updated with js bin link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand what you want is firing every child checkbox when click "select all" checkbox.

I think you can simply try call $scope.checked inside $scope.selectAll function, like this:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
$scope.tableRows = [{"oral": false, "cleaning": false, "filling": false, "xray": false,"crown": false, "canal": false, "dentures": false, "braces": false, "visible": false, "subtotal": 0},{"oral": false, "cleaning": false, "filling": false, "xray": false,"crown": false, "canal": false, "dentures": false, "braces": false, "visible": false, "subtotal": 0},{"oral": false, "cleaning": false, "filling": false, "xray": false,"crown": false, "canal": false, "dentures": false, "braces": false, "visible": false, "subtotal": 0},{"oral": false, "cleaning": false, "filling": false, "xray": false,"crown": false, "canal": false, "dentures": false, "braces": false, "visible": false, "subtotal": 0}];
$scope.prices = {oral: 100, cleaning: 50, filling: 75, xray: 200, crown: 125, canal: 100, dentures: 60, braces: 130}
$scope.selectAll = function(procedure, checked) {
    angular.forEach($scope.tableRows, function(person, index) {
      $scope.checked($scope.prices[procedure], index, checked, procedure);          
    });
};
$scope.checked = function(amount, position, checked, procedure) {
   $scope.tableRows[position][procedure] = checked;
   if (checked) {
      $scope.fired = 'FIRED!';
      $scope.dollarAmmount = $scope.dollarAmmount + amount;
      $scope.tableRows[position].subtotal += amount;
   } else if (!checked) {
      $scope.fired = '';
      $scope.dollarAmmount = $scope.dollarAmmount - amount;
      $scope.tableRows[position].subtotal -= amount;
   }
 }
}
```

Run on [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/xalezixiwi/edit?html,js,output)

I also optimize some lines of code. Hopefully it will solve your problem.

Cheers!

Comment: Great idea, I think I was just working too long, got code blocked and couldn't think of this simple solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try changing `selectall` method as bellow, hope it will help you.

```
$scope.selectAll = function(procedure, checked) {

  if (checked) {
  angular.forEach($scope.tableRows, function (person) {

    person[procedure] = true;
  })
} else if (!checked) {
  angular.forEach($scope.tableRows, function (person) {
    person[procedure] = false;
  })
}
};
```

Find working [JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/tuyoqazica/1/edit?html,js,output) Here